# When I use update() with tkinter my Label writes another line instead of rewriting the same text

Tags: python, tkinter

When I call the update() method using tkinter instead of rewriting the label it just writes the label under the previous call. I would like for this to rewrite over the previous line.

For Example:

```
root=Tk()
while True:
    w=Label(root, text = (price, time))
    w.pack()
    root.update()
```

Comment: Could you provide some example code that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: This is all you need to observe the problem. update writes below the last line instead of over it.

Answer (score 18):

Your problem is simply this: when you do `while True`, you create an infinite loop. The code in that loop will run until you force the program to exit. In that loop you *create* a label. Thus, you will create an infinite number of labels.

If you want to update a label on a regular basis, take advantage of the already running infinite loop - the event loop. You can use `after` to schedule a function to be called in the future. That function can reschedule itself to run again, guaranteeing it will run until the program quits.

Here's a simple example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.clock = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.clock.pack()

        # start the clock "ticking"
        self.update_clock()

    def update_clock(self):
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S" , time.gmtime())
        self.clock.configure(text=now)
        # call this function again in one second
        self.after(1000, self.update_clock)

if __name__== "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

No.

I suspect, without having seen it, that there are at least a couple of confusions in the code wDroter has written.  In general, it is NOT necessary in well-structured Tkinter code to use update() at all.  Here's a small example that illustrates updates to the text of a Label:

```
import Tkinter
import time

def update_the_label():
    updated_text = time.strftime("The GM time now is %H:%M:%S.", time.gmtime())
    w.configure(text = updated_text)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
w = Tkinter.Label(root, text = "Hello, world!")
b = Tkinter.Button(root, text = "Update the label", command = update_the_label)
w.pack()
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Run this.  Push the button.  Each time you do so (as long as your pushes differ by at least a second), you'll see the text update.

Comment: It is true that good `Tkinter` code will probably not need to call `update`, but this does not answer the question. It is perfectly fine, though possibly dangerous, to call `update` in `Tkinter`. The problem with the given code was that a new `Label` was being created and packed into the interface each time through the loop. There are at least three solutions to the problem: (1) destroy the `Label` and create a new one in its place, (2) edit the text in the `Label` to whatever value it should have, and (3) bind a `StringVar` to the `Label` object and change its value instead.

Comment: We're in agreement, Noctis Skytower.  Did wDroter supply code?  I didn't see that ("... given code"--where?  It's not showing up for me), and yours only after I had Answered.  I salute you for going to the trouble to construct your two examples.

Answer (score 3):

you want to use .configure insted

```
while True:
    w.Configure(text = (price, time))
    root.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of
`w.pack()`
you can write
`w.grid(row=0, column=0)`

`pack()` in tkinter usually packs things in a single row/column. It lays things out along the sides of a box. Whereas, `grid()` has more of a table like structure. So when you write `row=0` and `column=0`, it has no choice but to replace the previous if it exists. Because you have provided a very specific position instead of just pushing it to the window (which is hat `pack()` does)

Answer (score 1):

The `BadRoot` class should demonstrate the problem that you are having. You can comment out the call to the class to verify with a complete, working example. If you run the code as written, it will update the label in the `GoodRoot` class. The first line that is commented out shows an alternative syntax for changing the text in your label.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
from time import sleep
from random import random

class BadRoot(Tk):

    def __init__(self, price, time):
        super().__init__()
        self.labels = []
        while True:
            self.labels.append(Label(self, text=(price, time)))
            self.labels[-1].pack()
            self.update()
            sleep(1)

class GoodRoot(Tk):

    def __init__(self, callback):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = Label(self, text=str(callback()))
        self.label.pack()
        while True:
##            self.label['text'] = str(callback())
            self.label.configure(text=str(callback()))
            self.update()
            sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
##    BadRoot('$1.38', '2:37 PM')
    GoodRoot(random)
```

The problem with your original code is that a new label is created and packed into the interface each time through the loop. What you actually want to do is just edit the text being displayed by the label instead replacing the label with a new one. There are others ways of doing this, but this method should work for you.

Comment: @Oakley: Did you like the original code in the question better? There was no pause to allow someone to observe and contemplate what was happening. I could have just as easily used an `after` method call in `tkinter` instead of the `sleep` function.

Comment: No, the original code is no better, if I understand what you are asking. Regardless, when giving answers to people just starting to learn GUI programming you shouldn't give examples that make fundamental mistakes. At least, not without addressing the side effects and drawbacks as part of the answer.