# Display image with Tkinter and loop over time

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am currently using the PIL and Tkinter to display images.  I am streaming in images from a network and want to update my window automatically as the come in (much like a picture slideshow).  My code for displaying images works; however, i have to click the [x] button on the display window for the photo to update.   I want the window to automatically update as the new photo comes in, or at the very least, run the loop like every 5 seconds (so the window either closes itself and a new photo appears, or the photo just changes in the window).  My code is:

```
##I have a database of photos i want to display one by one...

im=image.open(currentphoto)
root=Tk()
canvas=...
photo=imageTk.PhotoImage(im)
item=canvas.create_image(10,10,anchor=NW,image=photo)

root.mainloop()

##want to display next photo either as it comes in or every 5 seconds (whichever is easier -- first method preferred)
```

This code works;

Comment: You'll need a timer and a callback.

Comment: You don't need to create a timer -- the event loop is able to run code at a particular point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the method `after` to schedule a command to run in the future. It's perfectly legal for this command to also call `after` to schedule itself to run again in the future.

For an example that shows a Label getting its text updated every second, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573031/when-i-use-update-with-tkinter-my-label-writes-another-line-instead-of-rewritin/7582458#7582458) to another question here on SO.

Comment: i have tried this and cannot seem to get this to work.  My entire script is written in a simple py script.  i do not use def or class or any other sort.  can you help knowing this?

Comment: Without seeing what you've tried Or seeing the errors you are getting I can't possibly guess what you did wrong. That being said, you simply _must_ use def to define a function you want to run on a periodic basis.

Comment: ok, hopefully this will make sense. My code runs as follows:     while True:

Comment: ok, hopefully this will make sense. My code runs as follows: #ive set some streaming of data to receive off network
#ive set some streaming of data to receive off network

while True:

data=sock.recv(4096)
image_index=xydist(min(data)) # This line is condensed but this is where i choose an index for my picture
current photo="C:\Python27\pics\%s" % (listing(image_index))

im=Image.open(currentphoto)
root=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(...)
photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
item=canvas.create_image(10,10,anchor=NW,image=photo)
root.mainloop()

Comment: then i looked at what you suggested, i tried:

import Tkinter as tk
class sample(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
 tk.Tk.__init(self,*args,**kwargs)
 root=Tk()

 data=sock.recv(4096)
 image_index=xydist(min(data)) # This line is condensed but this is where i choose an index for my picture
 current photo="C:\Python27\pics\%s" % (listing(image_index))

 im=Image.open(currentphoto)
 canvas=Canvas(...)
 photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
 item=canvas.create_image(10,10,anchor=NW,image=photo)
 root.mainloop()
 self.update_clock()

Comment: def update_clock(self):
 self.after(1000,self.update_clock)

if __name__=="__main__":
   app=sample()
   app.mainloop()

Comment: Your code is impossible to read. What it looks like is that your `update_clock` function does nothing but call itself over and over. It actually needs to do something, for example, update the image. Also, you have to start the update _before_ calling `mainloop`. Normally there is no code after you call that method.